# RSA in Java: BigInteger and byte[]

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

I'm trying to write RSA encryptring and decrypting functions in Java, but have some troubles: I think the convertion betwen BigInteger and byte[] or viceversa is causing it, some suggestions?

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] message, BigInteger n, BigInteger e) {
    BigInteger m = new BigInteger(1, message);
    BigInteger c = m.modPow(e, n);
    return c.toByteArray();
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipher, BigInteger n, BigInteger d) {
    BigInteger c = new BigInteger(1, cipher);
    BigInteger m = c.modPow(d, n);
    return m.toByteArray();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I have some troubles." Yeah, you've got troubles indicating what goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry, seems true. The decrypted array is not the same as the message array, i.e. the byte array after encrypting and decrypting is a lot smaller the the message array (ca. 14,000 vs 274 entries...).

Comment: Well, it works for me.

Comment: @gabse15 *Modulus* n, remember? You can magic that value back into something bigger. Hybrid cryptography.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes oh... so would it make sense to encrypt/decrypt blocks smaller than n?

Comment: I added one of my tests.

Comment: Yes. But note that raw / textbook RSA is not secure. For one, it always creates the same ciphertext for the same plaintext (encrypting "yes" twice obviously leaks information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message doesn't fit into the modulus, which makes it impossible to retrieve back the information lost when performing the modular arithmetic. For this reason RSA is often combined with symmetric encryption such as AES, where the AES key is encrypted instead.